# Using PyTest with hug and base_url

Tags: python, pytest, hug

I have a an api that is setup with

```
import hug
API = hug.API(__name__).http.base_url='/api'

@hug.get('/hello-world', versions=1)
def hello_world(response):
    return hug.HTTP_200
```

and I'm trying to test it with PyTest.

I'm trying to test the route with

```
import pytest
import hug
from myapi import api

...

def test_hello_world_route(self):
    result = hug.test.get(myapp, 'v1/hello-world')
    assert result.status == hug.HTTP_200
```

How can I test hug routes that have `http.base_url` configured?

I get a `404` errors regardless of the route path. I've tried

- `/api/v1/hello-world`
- `api/v1/hello-world`
- `v1/hello-world`
- `/v1/hello-world`

If I remove the `hug.API().http.base_url` setting then `v1/hello-world` works fine but my requirement is to have a `base_url` setup.

I've reviewed the documentation on the official hug github repo and various online sources such as ProgramTalk but I haven't had much success.

any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send your module (`myapp`) as the first argument to `hug.test.get()`.

Then you can use the full path `/api/v1/hello-world` as the second argument.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
# myapp.py

import hug

api = hug.API(__name__).http.base_url='/api'

@hug.get('/hello-world', versions=1)
def hello_world(response):
    return hug.HTTP_200
```

.

```
# tests.py

import hug
import myapp


def test_hello_world_route():
    result = hug.test.get(myapp, '/api/v1/hello-world')
    assert result.status == hug.HTTP_200
```

.

```
# run in shell
pytest tests.py
```

Comment: Sorry about that, that was a typo - I am indeed passing `myapp` to `hug.test.get`. I'm editing the post above to correct this.

Comment: Excellent :) glad I could help